# Button.onClick.AddListener Syntax Clarification When Using A Delegate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

From my research the following syntax works for setting a Unity 4.6+ Button's callback:

```
_button = GetComponent<Button>();
_button.onClick.AddListener(delegate { Test(); }); //works
_button.onClick.AddListener(Test);//works

public void Test()
{
    Debug.Log("Success");
}
```

However when I attempted to create a delegate and pass that it's not working

```
public delegate void AbilityButtonCallback();
public void SetCallback(AbilityButtonCallback callback)
{
   _button.onClick.AddListener(callback);
}

//ERROR: Error  2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 
'AbilityButtonCallback' to 'UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction'
```

Clearly its saying it can't make my AbilityButtonCallback at UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction type. However I never declared Test() as that type either, Test() is just a void function. So why is it I can pass Test as a parameter and its fine, but if I try to pass it a delegate with a void return type and 0 parameters it doesn't work?

Note:

I know that a lambda expression will work

```
_button.onClick.AddListener(() => { callback(); });
```

But I dont understand why you can pass a regular function pointer when my Delegate doesnt' work.

Comment: You cannot convert from one delegate type to another.  The C# compiler is however willing to convert an anonymous function or a method that has a signature that matches the expected delegate type, it auto-generates the delegate constructor call.  You must declare your method as `void SetCallback(UnityAction callback)`

Comment: Thank you very much that makes perfect sense